# iphone - autoreleasing a CGContextRef?

Tags: iphone

I have this method

```
-(CGContextRef) createPDFContext:(CGRect)inMediaBox path:(CFStringRef) path
{

   // bla bla
   // at some point I have

   CGContextRef myOutContext = CGPDFContextCreate (dataConsumer, &inMediaBox, NULL);

   // and then I have to return the value
    return myOutContext;
}
```

The problem is that myOutContext was not released and will leak.

if I put a CGContextRelease (myOutContext) before the return, then the reference will arrive invalid at the caller...

How do I solve that? Doing **return [myOutContext autorelease];**
will not work, as I suspected and tested.

thanks.

Comment: Who calls your method?  It seems like the caller ought to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your method has "Create" in its name, it's expected that the caller will be responsible for releasing the object. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029.

---

Update: Because this is a method and not a function, you should change it to start with "new" as described at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1.

Comment: thanks. I did that but Xcode gives me two errors. The first one on return myOutContext line (potential leak of object created on line ... - referring to the line where myOutContext was created) and the other error on the caller when I try to release the object, after using it (incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller)...

Comment: Ah yes, you've created a method, not a function. Rename your method `newPDFContext:path` and the analyzer should stop complaining.

Comment: Or you could ignore those analyzer warnings. They cancel each other out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow memory conventions.  Your method has the word "create" in it, which means that whoever *calls* that method is responsible for calling `CGContextRelease` on it when they are done with it.  If you don't like that idea, then you need to find some way of knowing when the caller is done with it.